# Fazer Requisição SOAP com Spring utilizando certificado A1

Tags: java, spring, soap, certificado-digital, spring-boot

Estou tentando fazer uma Requisição para o envio da NFe ao servidor do Sefaz SP, porém estou recebendo sempre o erro de certificado não encontrado. Eu criei um Bean que retorna o WebServiceTemplate, e esse é meu código:

```
@Value("/pathTo/certificate.pfx")
private String keyStorePath;

@Value("/pathTo/certificate.jks")
private String trustStorePath;

@Value("password")
private String storePassword;

/**
 * Template para envio via Sefaz-SP
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Bean
@Qualifier("sefaz")
public WebServiceTemplate getSefazWebServiceTemplate() throws Exception{
    SefazWebServiceClient sefazClient = new SefazWebServiceClient();
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath(NfeRecepcaoLoteResponse.class.getPackage().getName());
    sefazClient.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    sefazClient.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    Resource keyStore = new FileSystemResource(new File(keyStorePath));
    ks.load(keyStore.getInputStream(), storePassword.toCharArray());
    LOGGER.info("Loaded keyStore: "+ keyStore.getURI().toString());
    try {
        keyStore.getInputStream().close(); 
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //Do nothing
    }
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, storePassword.toCharArray());

    KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    Resource trustStore = new FileSystemResource(new File(trustStorePath));
    ts.load(trustStore.getInputStream(), storePassword.toCharArray());
    LOGGER.info("Loaded trustStore: "+trustStore.getURI().toString());
    try {
        trustStore.getInputStream().close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //Do nothing
    }
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(ts);

    HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender msgSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
    msgSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
    msgSender.setTrustManagers(trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers());

    sefazClient.setMessageSender(msgSender);


    return sefazClient.getWebServiceTemplate();
}
```

porém, sempre que eu faço a requisição eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso colocar esse certificado na requisição?

Comment: Você importou os certificados para sua máquina?

Comment: Ex: keytool -v -import -trustcacerts -alias exemploCertificado -file C:\exemploCertificado.cer -keystore C:\seukeystore -storepass senha123

Comment: Eu utilizei uma solução com o java que acessava o servidor buscando os certificados e me gerava o arquivo cacert ... ainda assim ele não funcionava nessa estrutura ... então eu mudei a estrutura toda do meu serviço e abandonei o WebServiceTemplate, passando a usar o Axis2 para fazer as comunicações (e funcionou perfeitamente os certificados gerados) ... infelizmente tinha um prazo um pouco apertado para a entrega ... 

Mas pelo que pesquisei, eu deveria alterar e implementar um MessageSender novo para aceitar essas chaves e as peculiaridades que o xml possui ...